# 404 error when trying to do a http get request to nodejs through javascript on azure

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

Hi my code is working in localhost, but when i deploy it to azure the http get request are not happening. getting 404 error 
Can someone help me to solve this.
This is m html page code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://######.azurewebsites.net:1337/incident_area',                     
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {    
           swals('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err,"error");
        }
      });
```

and this is my nodejs page

```
app.get('/incident_area', function (req, response) {
         console.log('params: ' + req.param('value'));
         var incident_area = req.param('incident_area');
         var search_name = req.param('search_name');
         var search_slack = req.param('search_slack');
         var search_email = req.param('search_email');
         response.send(JSON.stringify("hello"));
    });

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, function (req,res,next) {
     var host = server.address().address
     var port = server.address().port
     console.log("app listening at https://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

Comment: replace `url: 'https://######.azurewebsites.net:8081/incident_area',` with `url: '/incident_area'`.

Comment: let me know if that works for you

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: make sure your backend is working/running on azure

Comment: how to check that , since i just create a web app and upload the files that's all. Does other things need to be set up ?

Comment: check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

Comment: @SachinSharma Have you checked if the port remains 1337?

Comment: I've already read all things, nothing is helping

Comment: i try to run it in cmd in kudu and console.log is showing that it is running on 1337

Comment: port is automatically assigned by the server in such cases. Hardcoding a port doesn't work I think

Comment: @UsmanRana even if i am trying like this url: '/incident_area' it is still showing as 404

Comment: One small question. From your code I understand that you return not anything to client from your handler. Is it true?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov sorry i just hide the sending part, i'm sending a json result back

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works.

```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();

  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

 app.get('/incident_area', function (req, response) {
  console.log('params: ' + req.param('value'));
  var incident_area = req.param('incident_area');
  var search_name = req.param('search_name');
  var search_slack = req.param('search_slack');
  var search_email = req.param('search_email');
  response.send(JSON.stringify("hello"));
 });

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, function (req,res,next) {
var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
console.log("app listening at https://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

Comment: getting net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED when doing request

Comment: That occurs when you use proxy. Try this http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-err_tunnel_connection_failed-error-google-chrome/

Comment: I don't think it is because of crome, since i try to test it with different devices and with other os. the issue is with the environment set up of azure web app.

Comment: Definitely your node server is breaking. You need to check that in the console if is working or not.

Comment: Also check that the express npm module is installed on the server or not. This could also be the problem.

Comment: when i am trying to run node server.js  i am seeing bad request on console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168203/discussion-between-shahnawaz-aalam-and-sachin-sharma).